# Applescript Bundle and Python

Tags: python, bash, shell, osx-snow-leopard, applescript

Basically i want to launch a Python script from within an applescript bundle

So i have bundled the file (Controller.py) within the bundle

The script i need to run is

do shell script "PYTHONPATH=/Applications/gtk/inst/lib/python2.6/site-packages python /path/to/Controller.py

I want to access Controller.py from within the bundle

So how to you access bundled files via bash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `path to me` to get the location of the AppleScript bindle, then find your script relative to it:

```
set controller_script to (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Controller.py"
do shell script "PYTHONPATH=/Applications/gtk/inst/lib/python2.6/site-packages python " & (quoted form of POSIX path of controller_script)
```